# Autocomplete using Ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, .net-2.0

I want to provide an autocomplete option for a text in my web applciation . I have the master data in the SQL server database table. I beowsed in google and found how to use autocomplte. all the examples use web service to do this. I cannot create a web service to impltement this. Is it possible to implement autocomplete by looking up values from database in code behind ? If so any one can provide any sample links for reference ?

Thanks in advance,

Jebli

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the volume of data. There are 2 options:

- send it to the client pre-emptively (perhaps as json or html) in the page source
- let the client query it based on their input

The second is common if the data-volume is non-trivial, as you can query when (for example) they've entered 3 characters; *very* useful for names and other long lists.

Re the web-service; this doesn't have to be a full/complex web-service; just a simple route or ashx (for example) that returns the filtered data.

The [jquery autocomplete plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete) supports both scenarios, although this is now partly obsoleted by jquery ui plugin.

> Is it possible to implement autocomplete by looking up values from database in code behind

Well, that is at the *server* - so you're essentially talking about the same "web service" that you say you can't do... I also think you should separate out the 2 functions (create page vs provide auto-complete results) into separate files (/pages/whatever).

Comment: I have only one text box where i have to implement sutocomplte for the whole applciation. Should i create a new web service for this functionality . it would be better if there is any alternative way . thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Jebli - I think you've putting too much emphasis on "web service"; it is just a url that returns some data. An ashx will do the job. Aspx *can* do it, but it is harder to get the formatting right. An MVC route is easiest of all, obviously.

Comment: ok thanks for the comments. Your suggestions was very useful to me. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way would be to make a new aspx page that takes the autocomplete query as querystring parameters, looks up the result in a database and returns the response as XML og JSON.